# Java Generics and Static Factory Methods -- Syntax

Tags: java, generics, syntax, static, factory

Here's what I've got:

```
public class Node<T> {

    // instance variables
    private Node<T> next;
    private T data;

    // construct with data
    private Node(T data){
        next = null;
        this.data = data;
    }

    // construct without data
    private Node(){
        next = null;
        this.data = null;
    }

    // static factory method
    public static <T> Node<T> newNodeWithData(T data){
        return new Node<T>(data);
    }

    // static factory method
    public static <T> Node<T> newNode(){
        return new Node<T>();
    }
...
}
```

My question really just about the syntax of generics coupled with that of a static factory method. I don't really understand *why* we put the < T > before the return type in the method declaration. Is it kind of like typecasting? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you're asking about is *type inferrence*.

Since it's a static method it has to infer the Generic type from somewhere; You don't have an instance of the class. That's what the `<T>` means.

In the case of your method that takes no arguments it's actually inferring it from the target of the assignment. For example, say your method looked like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> getNewList() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

When using this method, `T` is inferred from the target (in this case `String`):

```
List<String> myList = MyClass.getNewList();
```

In your other static method where you have a Generic argument, `T` is being inferred from the type being passed in:

```
public static <T> List<T> getNewListWithElement(T element) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(element);
    return list;
}
```

Here, if you tried doing:

```
List<String> myList = MyClass.getNewListWithElement(new Integer(4));
```

It would tell you that your target type was wrong, and you needed a `List<Integer>`

Specifically this is covered in sections [15.12.2.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) and [15.12.2.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8) of the JLS.

Answer (score 9):

The reason you must decorate the static method with such sugar is because, as a static method, it does not inherit the `T` from the declaration of the class.

You could just as well do:

```
// static factory methods
public static <Q> Node<Q> newNode(){
    return new Node<Q>();
}

public static Node<String> newStringNode(String s){
    return new Node<String>(s);
}
```

A simple narrative to the declaration may assist:

```
// This static method would have a <T> parameter to the class if it was not static
public static <T> 
// It returns an object of type `Node` with generic parameter T
Node<T> newNode(){
    // And here it is doing it's business.
    return new Node<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an only way to parametrize a static method, as the original `T` in the Node declaration is bound to instance fields and methods of the Node. So you could write:

```
public static <T1> Node<T1> newNode(){
    return new Node<T1>();
}
```

The original `T` is bound to an instance of `Node` class and cannot be referenced in static context. This would result in a compilation error:

```
// ERROR
public static Node<T> newNode(){
    return new Node<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `<T>` is just the signal, that this method uses `T` as type variable. Without it, the compiler would think, `T` is a `class`, `interface` or `enum` that is declared somewhere and output an error. It is not the same `T` as used in your first line. You can replace the `T` in this method with any other letter, maybe that helps understanding.

Answer (score 0):

**T inferred from parameter**

```
public static <T> List<T> getNewListWithElement(T element)
```

How can the compiler make the difference between T as a class and T as a generic argument? The solution is to use  to specify T element is a generic and not a class/interface.

**T inferred from usage**

```
public static <T1> Node<T1> newNode(){
    return new Node<T1>();
}
```

Who will be T1 inside the method body if no declaration would be made?