# Kotlin static factory method with generics

Tags: kotlin, generics, factory-method

Found something similar with what I want to achieve for java - [java generics and static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751867/java-generics-and-static-factory-methods-syntax) also [implementing factory pattern with generics in java from baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-factory-pattern-generics).

In my case, I also want to have the factory as a static method, but not sure how to achieve it in Kotlin, or maybe the whole concept is wrong.
Shortly, there are certain types of `Notifiers`, each should handle a certain `NotificationInput` type. Basically they are also some kind of builders as they build up the `Notification` object from the input.

Considering the setup below, I get `Type mismatch. Required: Notifier<T> Found: DebugNotifier` (same for the other `Notifier` implementations).

```
interface Notifier<T> {
   fun issue(p: NotificationInput<T>): Notification

   companion object {
      fun <T> getNotifier(p: NotifierParameter): Notifier<T> = when(p.type){
          "0" -> DebugNotifier()
          "1" -> InfoNotifier()
          "2" -> ErrorNotifier()
      }
}
```

---

```
class DebugNotifier: Notifier<Debug>{
   override fun issue(p: NotificationInput<Debug>): Notification{
      return Notification(
         somField = p.someDebugFieldValue
      )
   }
}
```

---

```
data class NotificationInput<T>(
   val data: T
)
```

---

This is how I plan to call it: `Notifier.getNotifier<Debug>(notifierParameter).issue(notificationInput)`

How can this be achieved, or what would be a better configuration?

Comment: In this example `NotifierParameter` is not parameterized, so could the compiler know what is the type returned by `getNotifier()`?

Comment: ... so **how** could the compiler know ...

Comment: @broot `NotifierParameter` is just a parameter used for instance creation; `getNotifier()` is a generic function and has the type parameter placed before the name. if you mean the caller, that was an overlook, updated the original post

Comment: @MikeSpike If this code was allowed to compile, what would you expect to happen if the caller calls `Notifier.getNotifier<Debug>("2")`?

Comment: Yes, I meant the missing `<Debug>`. Now it is clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @broot already explained, the caller has control over 2 things here: the type argument `T` and the `NotifierParameter` argument, so the API is kinda broken because the caller could do:

```kotlin
Notifier.getNotifier<Debug>(NotifierParameter("2"))
```

What would you expect to happen here?

There are too many degrees of freedom in the inputs of `getNotifier()`, so the compiler cannot allow you to return `ErrorNotifier()` when you receive `"2"`, because someone could pass `<Debug>` as type argument.

You cannot compare this kind of API with Java, because Java's generics are broken and allow things that don't make sense.

Comment: actually I missed that completely. What would you suggest to have the generic `NotificationInput` in the `Notifier` implementation, while still instantiating the Notifier based on `NotifierParameter`?

Comment: `NotifierParameter` itself should encapsulate the generic type if you want this kind of behaviour, or it may have a polymorphic method itself which returns the `Notifier<T>` of the correct type, and you would avoid this